# devise confirmable edit template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, confirmation, confirmation-email

I have devise confirmable setup and working.  Everything functions, but..., the generated link is odd and when click it displays a blank page.

However when the link is clicked it does appear to confirm! the account.  My question is how to customize the blank page?  Where would I put a view template for it?  I copied all the devise layouts awhile ago, but I don't appear to have this page.  Or alternatively how can I make it redirect?

the link also looks a bit odd...

http://localhost:5000/users/confirmation.someusername?confirmation_token=yIle0ODY8QRyGi6QQnhk

I recently upgraded to 1.4.2 from 1.2, and I don't seem to recall it being blank before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change my routes as the newest version of Devise must use a new action other than new and create.

Before

```
resources :confirmations, :only => [:new, :create]
```

Fixed:

```
resources :confirmations
```